# Better way to send kafka message : JsonNode or Map<String, UserModel>?

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka with Spring Boot.

We can able to send kafka message in Json / String / Streams / JsonNode / Map. So right now in my project I want to send Map to one of my consumers.

So as a steps first we will convert map to JsonNode and then will send JsonNode. At consumer, we will deserilise this JsonNode into map and then will use.

I tried to send Map and I can able to send via kafka. When at consumer i am getting Json String.

So my question is which is the best way to implement in my requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion - **neither**.

Use Avro (or Protobuf) model classes that clearly define your types and [the Schema Registry](https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-kafka-stream-processing-yes-virginia-you-really-need-one/)

---

In other words, Kafka stores bytes. You can [pick **any** serialization format](https://eng.uber.com/trip-data-squeeze-json-encoding-compression/), and you better compress it as well

Comment: If i use Avro for format but I have Map object so how can send Map object ?

Comment: Did you read the Avro docs? _"Avro supports six kinds of complex types: records, enums, arrays,**maps**, unions and fixed"_. To be clear - Avro "maps" are the same as JSON objects (unordered key-value pairs). An Avro record is a map with **guaranteed fields**